# Spring Security configuration not authorizing properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, authorization, basic-authentication

Here is the config snippet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/registration")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home")
                .hasAuthority("USER")
                .antMatchers("/admin")
                .hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Here is another relevant class named CustomUserDetails:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        //return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the @service:

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if(user ==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found");
        }
        return new CustomUserDetails(user);
    }
}
```

The URL `/home` must be accessible to only USERS, but when I am sending a GET request to it, it is accessible and doesn't require any authorization or even authentication. I think I am overlooking something please help.

Comment: All your users are `USERS`, because of `return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));`.

Comment: Are you sure you are not accidentally already authenticated? Do you get the same behaviour in an incognito / private browsing window?